# PHP explode not working correctly

Tags: php, explode

This might seem trivial but it's hurting my head. Can someone explain the reason 
The http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php examples show (which I have trimmed).

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3"; // string
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
// after a var dump
array(3) {  [0]=> string(6) "piece1" 
            [1]=> string(6) "piece2" 
            [2]=> string(6) "piece3" }
```

This works lovely, removes all the spaces and does a nice little array to work with, however when I use something similar shown below

```
$path = "/test-gallery/2/"; // string
$urlpieces = explode("/", $path);
// after a var dump
array(4) {  [0]=> string(0) "" 
            [1]=> string(12) "test-gallery" 
            [2]=> string(1) "2" 
            [3]=> string(0) "" }
```

I get the first and last with an empty string. Why does it not remove the first and the last array elements? I can always add another step and remove it but the explode should take it all out shouldnt it?

Thanks for the advice in advance.

Comment: because this is how explode works!!!

Comment: use trim($path,"/"); before explode

Comment: As per the doc,each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

Comment: read explode() manual here http://in2.php.net/explode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can always add another step and remove it but the explode should
>   take it all out shouldnt it?

No. that is how [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) works. Delimiter is at both end so `""` string was found at both the ends after exploding

Comment: Thank you for the advice, as I mentioned it's probably a trivial question.

Comment: :) at least not now. Anyways I added  
$urlpieces = array_filter($urlpieces); Which did the job